# How to read txt file with slashes “/” with scanner input and reads certain parts?

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner, indexof

How do I get certain parts of a txt file and put them into arrays or strings?

I have already had a code that reads 25 items in the txt file.

```
    try {
        File file = new File("filepath");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        String[] ids = new String[25];
        String[] names = new String[25];//---- set your array length
        String[] prices = new String[25];
        String[] stocks = new String[25];
        int counter = 0;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String data = sc.nextLine();
            if (data.contains("/")) {
                String[] elements = data.split("/");
                ids[counter] = elements[0].trim();
                names[counter] = elements[1].trim();
                prices[counter] = elements[2].trim();
                stocks[counter] = elements[3].trim();
                // other elements[x] can be saved in other arrays
                counter++;
            }
        }
        image.setIcon(graphicsconsole[productTable.getSelectedRow()]);
        iteminfo.setText("" + names[productTable.getSelectedRow()]);
        itemdescription.setText("Price: P " + prices[productTable.getSelectedRow()]);
        itemstock.setText("Stocks: " + stocks[productTable.getSelectedRow()]);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exx) {
    }
```

As you can see, it is now arranged into arrays and I used them for the selection list for the `JTable`.

If I printed `ids[counter] = elements[0].trim();` it would be:

```
00011
00012   
00013 
00014  
00015
and so on...
```

The question is, how about if I want to get a certain part of a txt file? Example, instead of starting to read at ID number `00011`, I want it to read ID `00012` and so on?

Txt file content:

```
00011   / Call of Duty: Modern Warfare    / 2499       / 10 
00012   / The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt        / 1699       / 15 
00013   / Doom Eternal                    / 2799       / 20
00014   / Outlast 2                       / 1999       / 11
00015   / Forza Horizon 4                 / 2799       / 5
```

If I want to get the IDs after ID `00011`, the expected output would be:

```
00012
00013
00014
00015
```

I tried editing the `int counter = 0` and `counter++;` but it didn't output anything.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: you can use regex

Comment: @Erwin Hello, what kind of regex is needed?

Comment: get the id, match it with regex, if it match i.e contains id 00012 or bigger or until 00099 then take it

Comment: or may be you can only check the id? if it is bigger then 12 then take it?

Comment: take the last 2 digit then compare it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the below solutions reads all the file contents in memory, don't try to use it for very large files.

```java
File f = new File("filepath");
// read all lines
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(f.toPath());
lines.stream()
    // skip lines before 00013 (change here to your needs)
    .dropWhile(l -> !l.startsWith("00013"))
    // ensure the lines have '/' character
    .filter(l -> l.contains("/"))
    .forEach(data -> {
        // do something with each line, starting the one with 00013
        String[] elements = data.split("/");
        String id = elements[0].trim();
        System.out.println(id);
    });
// if you just want the IDs ...
lines.stream()
    .dropWhile(l -> !l.startsWith("00013"))
    .filter(l -> l.contains("/"))
    // get the ID for each line
    .map(l -> l.split("/")[0].trim())
    // print it
    .forEach(System.out::println);
// if you want the IDs to a List instead of printing ...
final List<String> ids = lines.stream()
    .dropWhile(l -> !l.startsWith("00013"))
    .filter(l -> l.contains("/"))
    .map(l -> l.split("/")[0].trim())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Just to illustrate the `dropWhile` part:

Input:

```
00011   / Call of Duty: Modern Warfare    / 2499       / 10 
00012   / The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt        / 1699       / 15 
00013   / Doom Eternal                    / 2799       / 20
00014   / Outlast 2                       / 1999       / 11
00015   / Forza Horizon 4                 / 2799       / 5
```

Code:

```java
lines.stream()
    .dropWhile(l -> !l.startsWith("00013"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
00013   / Doom Eternal                    / 2799       / 20
00014   / Outlast 2                       / 1999       / 11
00015   / Forza Horizon 4                 / 2799       / 5
```

Comment: Can I ask how can I make those arrays into indexes? For the use of

 `iteminfo.setText("" + names[productTable.getSelectedRow()]);`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Do you want to get the stocks based on ID or the name for that game?

Comment: It is used for the selection in `JTable`. It loads the txt file, gets the ids, item names and etc. Then when the user selects a row in the `JTable`, it will set JLabels.

Comment: But the JTable is populated already, since you can select a row, ain't it? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Oh, so when you select a row, you want some JLabels to be updated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213851/discussion-between-silviu-burcea-and-markzsnipe).